# Why does `npm install dragula` include 112 files?

Tags: npm

I have been using npm for a while, but I have never understood this point:

When a package is installed, like dragula, it includes all source files.

I don't really want all 112 files.  I just want dragula/dist files which is 4 files.

What is the rational behind including everything from the GitHub project?  Why not just include the distribution files?  If I wanted the entire project, I would go to GitHub and download it.  I use dragula as an example only.  All npm downloads that I have downloaded have the same issue.

The issue becomes magnified when using many such libraries.

Is there a way to reduce packages to just the files which are actually used at runtime?

The issue I run into is that after 50 such libraries, I have a nodes_module folder with over 20,000 files.  It all works, but I would like to reduce it to the files that are actually needed.

Comment: As far as I know, not via NPM. However you could just include it from a cdn if you don't need anything else from it. `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/$VERSION/dragula.min.js'></script>`

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear.  I have edited the last line, and removed my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the rational behind including everything from the GitHub project? Why not just include the distribution files? If I wanted the entire project, I would go to GitHub and download it.

It's up to each package/library to say which files are required via the `files` property in their `package.json`. If this is undefined it effectively includes everything, [which is the case with dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/blob/master/package.json).

[See the `files` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) for more details.

In other words this isn't so much a problem with npm as each package not doing a great job of explicitly defining which files are actually *required*.

If you don't like it I suggest opening an issue/PR on their Github page.

> I have a nodes_module folder with over 20,000 files. It all works,
>   but I would like to reduce it to the files that are actually needed.

Then you should be using something like webpack that will help you "build" your FE code so you have your own `dist` folder with only the file(s) you actually need.

Comment: Thank you! Good explanation.  And I just recently started learning webpack.  Will get that implemented soon.